# How to use Fluent NHibernate to create an IN clause

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Here I get a list of of agencies a rep has access to.

```
var agencies = _session.QueryOver<AgencyRep>()
    .JoinQueryOver<AgencyRepsSecondaryAgency>(r => r.AgencyRepsSecondaryAgencies)
    .Where(a => a.AgencyRepId == user.Id)
    .List();
```

After I get my list of agencies I want to do a SQL Search where the value is IN the agencies.id column.

```
var data = _session.QueryOver<Staging.Case>()
                .Where(x => x.AgencyId ???? agencies)
                .List();
```

Not sure how to implement something like this with fluent nhibernate.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = _session.QueryOver<Staging.Case>()
            .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.AgencyId).IsIn(agencies.Select(a => a.Id).ToArray())
            .List();
```

EDIT: If you don't need the agencies afterwards - you can optimize a bit by going:

```
var agencyIds = _session.QueryOver<AgencyRep>()
    .JoinQueryOver<AgencyRepsSecondaryAgency>(r => r.AgencyRepsSecondaryAgencies)
    .Where(a => a.AgencyRepId == user.Id)
    .Select(a => a.Id)
    .List<long>(); //if your .Id is of type long - replace with the correct type

var data = _session.QueryOver<Staging.Case>()
            .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.AgencyId).IsIn(agencyIds.ToArray())
            .List();
```

That saves a bit of data sent over the connection

Comment: This is awesome and worked just fine.  Thank you guys for the quick help and responses.  Learned a lot in the process.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, is untested but you can try:

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<AgencyRep>()
    .JoinQueryOver<AgencyRepsSecondaryAgency>(r => r.AgencyRepsSecondaryAgencies)
    .Where(a => a.AgencyRepId == user.Id)

var data = _session.QueryOver<Staging.Case>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.AgencyId).In(subquery)
    .List();
```